# import from utils import module returns cannot import even though other modules from same file work

Tags: python

I have a utils file from a GitHub repo and I added some simple functions to it (to unpick and pickle) and the import statement

```
from utils import existing_module, unpicklefile
```

returns the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'unpicklefile' from 'utils'
```

but the other functions import fine, so this isn't a `sys.path` error.

Help :D

Comment: Check the spelling.  Based on the other name it's probably `unpickle_file`.

Comment: Please help us help you with your problem by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A link to the GitHub repo you're following would help

Comment: what repo do you mean? Add link in question (not in comment). And then we can check in documentation or source code if there is `unpicklefile`. Document [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) suggests to use `lower_case_names` for functions - so it can be `unpickle_file`. But you should check it in repo's documentation or source code.

Comment: If you are adding a new method did you accidently indent it so it became a local function of another method in the utils module?

Comment: Sorry folks, it seems to work after a re-start. Strange error